# Check mail attachment

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, outlook

I am using vb.net to display email from outlook express! Everything work fine but when some message has attachment, i can not display message that email has attachment!

This is my code:

```
   Private Sub LoginButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoginButton.Click
    Dim oItem
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Message As MAPI.Message
    Dim items As String() = New String(6) {} '      Items are the sender name,subject and date and      read/unread value
    Dim PrSenderEmail, PrBodyEmail
    Session = CreateObject("MAPI.Session") ' we use a session object of MAPI Component
        Session.Logon(ProfileName:=Me.UserId.Text, ProfilePassword:=Me.Password.Text)
        Session.MAPIOBJECT = Session.MAPIOBJECT '
        Folder = CObj(Session.Inbox) ' choose the folder
        Application = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Namespace1 = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Namespace1.Logon()
        ' for getting the sender name and avoid security validation of Outlook/Exchange server 2003
        ' we are using the "Redemption" component
        sItem = CreateObject("Redemption.SafeMailItem")
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor ' show we're busy doing the sort
        ListInbox.BeginUpdate() ' Notify that update begins
        ListInbox.Items.Clear()
        i = 0 ' first email message is 0
        For Each Message In Folder.Messages
            Try
                i = i + 1 ' increment to the next email message
                'get e-mail from the Inbox, can be any other item
                oItem = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(6).Items(i) ' GetDefaultFolder(6) refers to Inbox
                sItem.Item = oItem
                'sItem is an object of Redemption COM and is used to get the senders name
                items(0) = sItem.SenderName()
            Catch
                items(0) = "error"
            End Try
            Dim objApp As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application
            'Get Mapi NameSpace
            Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace = objApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
            Dim oMsg As Outlook.MailItem
            Dim pp As String
            Dim b As Integer
            Dim objAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
            pp = Message.StoreID
            items(1) = Message.Subject
            items(2) = Message.TimeReceived
            items(4) = Message.Subject
            items(5) = Message.Size
            Dim objInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
            Dim objItems As Outlook.Items = objInbox.Items
            items(5) = Message.Size.ToString / 1000 & "kb"
            If Message.Unread = True Then
                items(3) = "unread"
            Else
                items(3) = "read"
            End If
            ListInbox.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(items))
        Next
        ListInbox.EndUpdate() ' Notify that update ends
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default
    End If
End Sub
```

How I can display message that email has attachment?

Comment: looks like you have cut a pasted 3 sets of code here ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Message.Attachments.Count ?